# Is there an AngularJS directive to use ngClick, which only fires up on touch events?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to call a method only when the input was initiated through a touch screen? e.g. on the Surface Studio you have two possible input devices - mouse and touch screen.

I want to react differently based on the type of input device used. As far as I know, feature detection won't work as it only tells me if a device is capable of smth. But not if a specific action was called via touch screen.

Comment: Tried ngTouch? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch

Comment: ngTouch only provides primitive gesture events or did I miss smth?

Comment: I don't know, I asked you if you tried it... :-)

Comment: Well, I already took a look at it - but it seems to only provide ngSwipeLeft and Right directives.

Comment: Ok, seems like ontouch only fires on touch inputs. Thought it would also fire on mouse events. I'll write a quick directive an post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I scribbled the following directive.

It's not even close to good but it perfectly fits my needs for now.

```
angular.module('app').directive('tap', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        compile: function($element, attr) {    
            return function (scope, element) {    
                element.on('touchstart', function(event) {    
                    var callback = function() {
                        $parse(attr['tap'])(scope, {$event: event});
                    };    
                    scope.$apply(callback);    
                });    
            };    
        }
    };
});
```

Usage:

```
<a tap="mainCtrl.someTouchscreenAction()">Tap</a>
```

Maybe someone else will find it useful.